# Configure ufw pptpd and dnsmasq on the same server

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, dnsmasq, ufw, pptpd

I've got a an ubuntu 14 server running both `pptpd` and `dnsmasq`.
 
I'm having trouble configuring `ufw` to allow `pptp` clients to resolve their DNS queries using the local `dnsmasq` server.

I've correctly configured both pptpd and dnsmasq (there are a few other services on the server using dnsmasq) and `pptpd` clients are able to resolve websites when `pptp-options` is set directly to Google's public dns: `ms-dns 8.8.8.8`. 

If I set `ms-dns` to `127.0.0.1` they aren't able to resolve. I've also tried a number of different NAT configurations and different internal IP's (I realise setting the DNS to 127.0.0.1 will cause the client to try and resolve the DNS to their local machine and have tried setting it to the servers public IP address as well, but naturally this is blocked by UFW).
I'm trying **not** to make dnsmasq open to the world.

How can I configure `ufw` to correctly allow connecting pptp clients to resolve using the localhost?

I have confiured pptpd by following this guide: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119534/easiest-way-to-setup-ubuntu-as-a-vpn-server

Thanks for any guidance/advice/support!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to open `/etc/default/ufw` and change the option "DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY" from "DROP" to "ACCEPT"? It did the trick for me.